# What is being represented by this 2 images?

Tags: trigonometry, parametric, curves

**image 1**

[image]

**image 2**

[image]

It's possible that *image 1* is showing some kind of methods for building polygons out of trigonometric functions ?

It's also possible that *image 2* is a quadratic bezier curve ?

Comment: Image 1 is showing the "vertical distance" of the endpoint of the radius arm from the $ \ x-$ axis (the $ y-$ component of the radius vector) as a function of angle for each geometric figure.  Image 2 is tracing a curve known as a _lemniscate_.  I'm not sure the intent of the animation, but it appears to be interpretable as shown that it can be traced by a fixed point on a particular mechanical linkage.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner I can draw a parametric pentagon using trigonometric formulas ? Also how I can compute the position of the red dot in the second image ? There are some algorithms for computing this kind of movement with this kind of links ?

Comment: To the first question, yes, although it would require a "piecewise" function, since you would need to describe each of the five sides with an individual line.  On your second question, it appears that the red dot tracing the lemniscate is the midpoint of segment CD, the endpoints of which are determined by the "rotors" AC and BD.  I can't tell for sure if the lengths of AC and BD are constant from the animation, but there is a way to write equations for this in any case.  I've never worked that out myself, but I suspect it's online somewhere as well if this image is.

Comment: As I was typing that, a childhood memory returned of seeing linkage demonstrations of that sort in a museum.  (In the "software age", such "analog" demonstrations seem quaint, but are sometimes useful things to know about.)  In the second section of this little paper [ http://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.3078.pdf ], there is a discussion of using a linkage to trace the lemniscate, applying a definition of the curve.  There is likely more discussion of this aspect elsewhere online...

Comment: The lemniscate in picture #2 is certainly not a quadratic Bezier curve. A quadratic Bezier curve is a parabola, so it doesn't have any inflexions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how we can produce the figures in image 1.  The graphs are showing the $ \ y-$ coordinate of the point being "swept along" on each curve.

The circle is simple because familiar trigonometric functions can be defined in terms of a circle.  For a circle of radius $ \ a \ , $ the coordinates of the point are just $ \ (a \cos \theta \ , \ a \sin \theta) \ , $ with $ \ \theta \ $ being the angle measured (counter-clockwise) from the positive $ \ x-$  direction.  [Keep in mind that, in the animations, the graphs are being drawn "right to left".]

The square of side $ \ 2a \ $ , having four straight sides lying along the lines $ \ x \ = \ \pm a \ $ and $ \ y \ = \ \pm a \ , $ requires a piecewise function with four "branches":

$$ \sigma(\theta) \ = \ \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}( \ a \ , \ a \ \tan \theta \ ) \ ,&
-\frac{\pi}{4} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{4}\\(  \ a \ \cot \theta \ , \ a ) \ ,&
\frac{\pi}{4} \le \theta \le \frac{3\pi}{4}\\( \ a \ , \ -a \ \tan \theta \ ) \ ,&
\frac{3\pi}{4} \le \theta \le \frac{5\pi}{4}\\(  \ -a \ \cot \theta \ , \ a ) \ ,&
\frac{5\pi}{4} \le \theta \le \frac{7\pi}{4}\end{array}\right.  $$

The hexagon depicted is correspondingly more complicated and I won't do all of it here.  We will call the lengths of the sides $ \ a \ . $  Except for the vertical sides, the rest make 30º angles to the "horizontal", so their slopes are $ \ \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \ . $  Since the altitude of an equilateral triangle is $ \ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  a \ ,  $ the right vertical side lies on the line $ \ x \ = \ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  a \ , $ so that branch of the piecewise function is

$$ ( \ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  a \ , \ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  a \ \tan \theta \ ) \ , \  -\frac{\pi}{6} \ \le \ \theta \ \le \ \frac{\pi}{6} \ \ .  $$

The next side in the counter-clockwise direction has a slope of $ \ -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \ $ and a $ \ y-$ intercept of $ \ a \ $ , so it lies on the line $ \ y \ = \ a \ - \ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} x \ . $  In polar coordinates, this is

$$ r \ = \ \frac{a}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}  \cos \theta \ + \ \sin \theta} \ \ . $$

The branch of the piecewise function definition covering this side is then

$$ ( \ \frac{a \ \cos \theta}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}  \cos \theta \ + \ \sin \theta} \ , \ \frac{a \ \sin \theta}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}  \cos \theta \ + \ \sin \theta} \ ) \ , \  \frac{\pi}{6} \ \le \ \theta \ \le \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ \ .  $$

The branch definitions for the other four sides of the hexagon can be determined analogously.

Comment: I'm assuming that there is no generalized equation for drawing polygons in terms of trigonometric functions ? It's the same process used here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=person%20curve which means drawing the figure in terms of curves ? Why the hexagon is so hard ? What is the fastest way to compute an hexagon ?

Comment: Even doing the pentagon, which you asked about earlier, takes a bit of work becuase each side lies on a distinct line from any of the others.  A regular polygon with $ \ n \ $ sides requires $ \ n \ $ branches in the piecewise definition.  It helps a little when $ \ n \ $ in even because you have opposite sides with the same slope, as you see with the square above.  Straight sides are not convenient to describe using polar (circular trigonometric) functions; it can be done, but it's not really what they do best...

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out this formula:

$\theta \in [0,2\pi] $

$r = \sqrt{1 + tan^2[|mod(\theta,\frac{2\pi}{n})-\frac{\pi}{n}|-\frac{\pi}{n}]} = sec(|mod(\theta,\frac{2\pi}{n})-\frac{\pi}{n}|-\frac{\pi}{n}) $

For example, in matlab:

```
n = 5;
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,1000);
r = sec(abs(mod(theta,2*pi/n)-pi/n)-pi/n);
plot(r.*sin(theta),-r.*cos(theta),'linewidth',2);
axis equal;
```

Displays this:

[image]

Comment: This works. All the other formulas I found online did not keep the radius constant. Could you show or point me in a direction for the derivation?

Comment: Dear @Saksham, I really can't remember. It was one and a half year ago and I probably did it in a dirty paper or so... however, the fact that I am using the absolute value of the modulo less half the way means that I derived the radius for just half of a side using Pythagorean theorem, and used this workaround to extend it to the full 2π rad. The conversion from sqrt(1+tan²) to sec is immediate. Please have a try with half side. Nevertheless I will try to derive it again and post something tomorrow. Today is national holiday in Spain! 